# Check three cells in one row and unhide the row if one cell has specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has hidden rows 17-111. Data is added to three cells in each row (Columns P,Q & R).

The data comes from Userforms where the user has three option buttons to choose from. Depending on the option, the result of either  "Pass", "Fail" or "NA" is populated into each of the cells in the range P17-R111.

I need to unhide all rows where "Fail" is in any of the P, Q or R column cells for that row.
e.g. If cell R57 is a "Fail" and cell P66 is "Fail", then the rows 57 and 66 need to be unhidden.

I have tried variations of code found searching the net, but I get a result where rows are unhidden only where column P has a "Fail", not where the P cell has no fail but other cells in the same row do.
e.g. If cell P57 has a "Pass", but cell  R57 has a fail, the row remains hidden.

This is my latest (and more simple) attempt:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim RangeToUnhide As Range

    For Each cel In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P17:R111")
        If cel = "Fail" Then
            If RangeToUnhide Is Nothing Then
                Set RangeToUnhide = cel
            Else
                Set RangeToUnhide = Union(RangeToUnhide, cel)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    RangeToUnhide.EntireRow.Hidden = False    

End Sub
```

I tried changing the range to ("P17:P111") and then run two further copies of the code for ranges in Q and R. All I get is rows that unhide where the P cell is a 'Fail", the Q and R cells are ignored.

Comment: I can't replicate that. Are you sure the cells contain "Fail" without any trailing spaces and that it is always upper case F? Also, please get in the habit of indenting your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Rookie error... yes the person that created the main spreadsheet had a blank cell in front of fail in the formula that I did not notice.!!!  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
Sub Hide()
Dim cel As Range
Dim RangeToUnhide As Range

For Each cel In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7:B11")
'Change Name of Sheet & Range as per your use
If cel = "A" Then
'Change Value as per your use
If RangeToUnhide Is Nothing Then
Set RangeToUnhide = cel
Else
Set RangeToUnhide = Union(RangeToUnhide, cel)
End If
End If
Next
RangeToUnhide.EntireRow.Hidden = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57247918/edit) your answer to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the code does not work; it actually hides the rows.

Comment: Then Change the True to False

Comment: Sub UnHide()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim RangeToUnhide As Range

    For Each cel In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7:B11")
    'Change Name of Sheet & Range as per your use
    If cel = "A" Then
    'Change Value as per your use
    If RangeToUnhide Is Nothing Then
    Set RangeToUnhide = cel
    Else
    Set RangeToUnhide = Union(RangeToUnhide, cel)
    End If
    End If
    Next
    RangeToUnhide.EntireRow.Hidden = False


End Sub}

Answer (score 0):

The above code is for hide use this for unhide

```
Sub Unhide()
Dim cel As Range
Dim RangeToUnhide As Range
For Each cel In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7:B11")
'Change Name of Sheet & Range as per your use
If cel = "A" Then
'Change Value as per your use
If RangeToUnhide Is Nothing Then
Set RangeToUnhide = cel
Else
Set RangeToUnhide = Union(RangeToUnhide, cel)
    End If
End If
Next
RangeToUnhide.EntireRow.Hidden = False


End Sub
```